# tomcat 7 Form based authentification

Tags: security, authentication, tomcat, servlets, form-authentication

given a Servlet HelloServlet:

```
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public HelloServlet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


   @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.print("hello my Friend: " + request.getRemoteUser());
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("This is the Test Servlet");

    Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
        out.print("<br/>Header Name: <em>" + headerName);
        String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
        out.print("</em>, Header Value: <em>" + headerValue);
        out.println("</em>");
    }
    }
....
}
```

with a declared tomcat security policy in web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>my application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login-failed.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

and tomcat-roles definitions in conf/tomcat-users.xml

```
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
```

the realm in "server.xml" is:

```
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>
```

,I tried to access the Servlet "HelloServlet" with url localhost/jsfWorkgroup/HelloServlet.

like expected, I am (re)directed to the login-page:

```
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Login to the Tomcat-Demo application:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="j_username" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="j_password"/ ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Go" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

No matter which id-Token I used:

1. username:tomcat  passwort:tomcat
2. username:both passwort:tomcat

I still come to the failure /login-failed.jsp.

here is my take on this: tomcat acts on redirect me to the to login page, but does not read the conf/tomcat-users.xml to valid my login(even after several reboots).

what do you think about it ?

configuration: Tomcat 7.0.23, Eclipse-Indigo

Comment: Can you post your **<Realm>** config from server.xml?

Comment: @pd40 I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Double-check the comments in `conf/tomcat-users.xml`: everything is commented-out to prevent any kind of access in a default configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following to proposition of @pd40 I tried the examples/jsp/security/protected/ examples but not in the Eclipse IDE where Tomcat is usually embedded along with the other servers (Glassfish, JBoss, ect..) , rather I started the tomcat server as standalone (in its /bin directory) .. and there it works.

but when it's attemped to run security based Web-application in Tomcat within Eclipse, it failed again, even using the configuration described above.

I don't know if I am right but Web-Application Security is only supported when tomcat runs outside of eclipse..

Answer (score 1):

The tomcat example web.xml includes the following section below `<login-config>`:

```
<!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
<security-role>
  <role-name>role1</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
  <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
</security-role>
```

which you may need.

---

Tomcat includes an example war which contains an auth using **tomcat-users.xml** similar to what you are trying. If **tomcat home/webapps/examples** is deployed try accessing **http://localhost/examples/jsp/security/protected/**. Make sure the XML comments around the role/user section of **tomcat-users.xml** have been removed. They are commented out by default.

```
<!-- Un comment me 
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
```

---

You can consider bumping up the [logging](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) to help diagnose the auth issue.

Comment: I added it but noting really changed.

Comment: Is your login.jsp posting j_username & j_password in the form field?

Comment: I tried the examples/jsp/security/protected/ locally. It did not work until I un-commented the role/user section. Just checking. You have probably already done this..

Comment: yep .. it still remains the same

Comment: +1 for the examples/jsp/security/protected/. indeed it worked as expected but only when I deploy the webapp War outside eclipse in the stand-alone tomcat... so I began to think and ...

Answer (score 1):

This is too late for me to answer but maybe someone coming here may find this useful.

Actually if you are facing the problem of not getting the tomcat configuration to work through eclipse and running outside it, then just delete the server from eclipse servers tab and add again. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Never too late Prasad.

Comment: You can just update your tomcat conf in the "Servers" project automatically created by Eclipse. Update tomcat-users.xml for instance and restart Tomcat. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have restricted access to your content by 
defining secured pages in web.xml:

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

that wildcard is refering to all pages in content path.
So you obtain an infinitive loop of redirections to login page.

Comment: This explains the issue indeed, but do you have a solution?

Comment: You have to separate default content of application which has to be secured from login and "loginerror" page, just put them in different directories. For example content in /work/ and login, "loginerror" in /loginPages/. Ofcourse you have to change web.xml settings respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if you change the configuration of users in the tomcat-users.xml that is embedded in eclipse you must restart eclipse not just the server for the new users to be recognised. I guess that eclipse caches the tomact-user.xml file.